# Accessing CSV files in .NET Core Project in Docker Container

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core

I am having trouble accessing CSV files in a .NET Core Project in a Docker Container (Linux), it works fine in debug mode but not in release mode (with an error saying cannot find file). Any ideas what may be wrong? The project has a folder called 'Data' with CSV files in it.

```
    [Route("GetTestFile")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetTestFile()
    {
        var fileName = "testdata.csv";
        var filePath = Path.Combine("Data", fileName);
        return new FileContentResult(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath), "text/csv") { FileDownloadName = fileName };
    }
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY PVT_Matching_Algorithm/PVT_Matching_Algorithm.csproj PVT_Matching_Algorithm/
RUN dotnet restore PVT_Matching_Algorithm/PVT_Matching_Algorithm.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/PVT_Matching_Algorithm
RUN dotnet build PVT_Matching_Algorithm.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish PVT_Matching_Algorithm.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "PVT_Matching_Algorithm.dll"]
```

The exception screen looks like this :

[image]

Comment: With that code that simply hides the error you'll never find out and we can't help either. *Log* the error, don't hide it. In any case ASP.NET Core itself takes care of returing a `500` error and displaying either an explanatory page in developer mode or an empty error page in production. This `try/catch` actually causes harm

Comment: In any case, without the exception or any other information one can only guess that the file doesn't exist where you think it does

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `filePath`?

Comment: The short answer is that `"Data"` should be replaced with a fully qualified path.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @PanagiotisKanavos. I have changed the code.

Comment: @ajs117 and? What is the exception thrown? Post the full exception as returned by `Exception.ToString()` in the question itself. This includes the stack trace

Comment: *Does* the `/app/Data` directory exist? The path in the screenshot is an absolute one.

Comment: @mjwills the exact value of `filePath` is Data/testdata.csv

Comment: @mjwills I have tried the method of using `IHostingEnvironment` for a fully qualified path but it still yields /app/Data/testdata.csv

Comment: Thats should be related to the way docker works when debugging/testing I think. When you run a debugging session, your project files will be created on your files and linked within the container. So the container never changes. When you build and deploy it for production, your application files are copied inside the container, creating a new layer on top of the base image

Comment: Make sure you copy the given file inside your container (as directive in `Dockerfile`)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right.
You have to inject IHostingEnvironment appEnvironment.
And then you can do like that:

```
var filePath = Path.Combine(_appEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "Data/testdata.csv");
```

Answer (score 0):

You mention debug mode vs release mode, the relevant lines in the Dockerfile are:

```
RUN dotnet build PVT_Matching_Algorithm.csproj -c Release -o /app
RUN dotnet publish PVT_Matching_Algorithm.csproj -c Release -o /app
```

The exception screen says the directory can't be found, i.e. /app/Data

When you publish an app, dotnet copies only the runtime files needed to the publish directory (not source, etc)

The first part of the multi-stage Dockerfile copies in all of your source to workdir /src, builds them, and the publishes to /app. It is use an aspnetcore-build image, with all the build tools.

The last part of the multi-stage Dockerfile copies just the published files, and uses an aspnetcore runtime image, so only has runtime files.

If the file is missing when you do a Release build, but not when you do a Debug build, then it might be configure to conditionally be included/published.

To test this, run the `dotnet publish` command locally and compare:

```
dotnet publish PVT_Matching_Algorithm.csproj -c Debug -o publish-Debug
dotnet publish PVT_Matching_Algorithm.csproj -c Release -o publish-Release
```

If it is missing, then check your .csproj file and there is probably a condition to only include the file in Debug mode; remove the conditional, so that it is included in both build types, and test locally.

*NOTE:* Rather than Debug vs Release configuration, it may be a case that by "Debug" you actually meant accessing one of the other containers, like the "build" container, for the purposes of debugging. In this case the `dotnet build` may have copied files across that are not included in `dotnet publish` (or even be using the /src directory directly) -- this can be checked as above by locally running `dotnet publish` and checking the output, then including the file as needed.